# displaying dates between in codeigniter php not working

Tags: php, mysql, date, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have a codeigniter website, where i am trying to display some dates using below code:

```
function searchstatus($clients,$fromdate,$todate,$deliveryboy)
{
    $this->db->where('date >=', $fromdate);
    $this->db->where('date <=', $todate);

    if ($clients) {
        $this->db->like('customer', $clients);
    }
    if ($deliveryboy) {
        $this->db->like('deliveryboy', $deliveryboy);
    }

    $this->db->order_by('date','ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get('delivered');
    return $query->result();
}
```

my table is like below:

[image]

however one date is being missed here '2022-06-22'

can anyone please tell me what could be wrong in here, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue to displaying dates in between, is in your like() clause, please try bellow code it's work for me.

`$this->db->where("( date >='".$fromdate."' AND date <='". $todate."')");`

Comment: it doesnt work bro, its showing unknown column error

Comment: $this->db->where("( date >='".$fromdate."' AND date <='". $todate."')"); try this one with your table column name

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where("( date >='".$fromdate."' AND date <='". $todate."')");
```

use your table column name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).